# Corrupt .docx when using MemoryStream & StreamWriter

Tags: vb.net, httpresponse, memorystream

I am prototyping a method for my server to serve documents to a user which are dynamically created from the database. As a proof of concept I have created a very simple WebApp designed to serve a .docx file on a button click.

```
    Private Sub lbWord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbWord.Click
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim streamWord = New StreamWriter(ms)
        streamWord.WriteLine("Loads of stuff")
        For index = 1 To 10
            streamWord.WriteLine(String.Format("Number {0}", index))
        Next
        streamWord.Flush()
        Response.Clear()

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString + "_Test.docx")
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ms.Length)
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.GetBuffer())
    End Using
    Response.End()
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
End Sub
```

Unfortunately whenever I open the .docx after downloading MS Word is flagging it as being corrupted.

I suspect it has something to do with either a) not closing the response correctly or b) additional bytes at the end of the file. But I cannot figure out how to rectify this issue. I have done a lot of googling and tried variations of Response.End/Response.Flush/Response.Close, Response.SomethingWrite or ms.WriteTo/ms.CopyTo but they all return the same corruption message.

Am I correct in using MemoryStreams and a StreamWriter or is there a better approach?

If anyone could highlight any issues which may cause the corruption I would be grateful.

Kind Regards,

Cuddles :)

Comment: Saying that it is of the Open XML format doesn't make it so. Open XML has a special structure, you can't just write plain text in it and call it a `.docx` file and think that it would work.

Comment: Think of it this way: You have a jar full of strawberry jam. On that jar you place a label that says "Blueberry jam", however just because you placed that label there it doesn't change the fact that the jar actually contains strawberry jam. You need to change _the contents_ of the jar as well in order for it to correspond with the label.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go. You should work with the Microsoft Word Object Library.

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent, so the problem is the StreamWriter? I need to create something that word actually understands?

Comment: @MarcoSadowski the Microsoft Word Object Library is only available to Office and SharePoint projects. How can I use this in a Web Application?

Comment: A Microsoft word document is actually a zipped folder with several files inside it, and most of the actual document text is stored in xml format. Create a word document, right click it and extract all to take a peek. You'll see that what's in there is quite different from a simple text file, which is why Word cannot open the files you've created. You can use the Interop classes to create a word document in a .net web application.

Comment: @Cuddles : Yes. Have a look at the Word Interop like soohoonigan suggested.

Comment: Thanks for persisting with me. I have managed to get it working by replacing the StreamWriter with Word Interop. Any way I can credit a comment with the answer?