# C# Reading and writing a docx file, simple file copy

Tags: c#, docx, streamreader

I am facing a really strange problem:

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( @"test.docx");
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"test2.docx");
    sw.Write(s);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
```

When I than try to open the test2.doxc, Word tells me it is not readable.
But it should be an exakt copy?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48928022/9936356. "A Microsoft word document is actually a zipped folder with several files inside it, and most of the actual document text is stored in xml format. Create a word document, right click it and extract all to take a peek. You'll see that what's in there is quite different from a simple text file, which is why Word cannot open the files you've created. You can use the Interop classes to create a word document in a .net web application."

Comment: I know. But why does my code not create an exakt copy of the orgininal file?

Comment: Use [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `StreamReader` reads **characters**. But docx file contains **binary** data.